# JQuery click event is not working on dynamically created ul Li list in mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

In my MVC project, on a button click event (in jQuery) I am populating a dynamically created Html `ul Li` list. It is working fine but when I am using jQuery click event on dynamically created  `ul Li` , it is not working.
The code is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('ul.cls-ul li').click(function(e) { 
         alert(this);
     }); 
})
```

Is there any better solution?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: For dynamically created elements, it's necessary to delegate events from parent elements that are already there when the page is initially loaded using on(). Like e.g. $(document).on("click", "ul.cls-ul li", function() {   });

Answer (score 0):

You need change click function format to

```
$(document).on('click','ul.cls-ul li',function(){
  alert(this);
});
```